# other open source alternatives to codahale's "metrics"?

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx, metrics, yammer

I came across the [metrics project](http://metrics.codahale.com/) from codahale, and I believe that it is used at Yammer.  I like this solution, but want to know if there are other open source alternatives with similar capabilities.

Comment: Hate these "not constructive" crap closings. Google brought me here, and it was EXACTLY the stuff I needed!

Comment: I agree with @stolsvik this is not incredibly easy to find and the fact that people get so anal about a searchable answer database seems a little silly.

Comment: Agree. What is not constructive about this question? This is such useful info

Comment: so agree with @stolsvik, this question is 100% useful. This forum should include all sorts of questions that are useful. Over policing kills useful questions and information.

Answer (score 20):

Some suggestions:

- [Perf4J](https://github.com/codehaus/perf4j): Perf4J is a set of utilities for calculating and displaying performance statistics for Java code.
- [ERMA](http://erma.wikidot.com/): ERMA (Extremely Reusable Monitoring API) is an instrumentation API that has been designed to be applicable for all monitoring needs.
- [javasimon](https://code.google.com/p/javasimon/): Java Simon is a simple monitoring API that allows you to follow and better understand your application. Monitors (familiarly called Simons) are placed directly into your code and you can choose whether you want to count something or measure time/duration.
- [Glassbox](http://glassbox.sourceforge.net/glassbox/Home.html): The Glassbox troubleshooter is an automated troubleshooting and monitoring agent for Java applications that diagnoses common problems with one-click.
- [InfraRED](http://infrared.sourceforge.net/versions/latest/): InfraRED is a tool for monitoring performance of a Java EE application and diagnosing performance problems. It collects metrics about various aspects of an application's performance and makes it available for quantitative analysis of the application.

Answer (score 17):

Netflix's [Servo](https://github.com/Netflix/servo) is somewhat simliar in spirit of Metrics. It is also a Java library based on annotation on the metrics to observe, which can be polled periodically from within the JVM and write it out to a backend server. It also exposes the metrics via JMX.

Answer (score 5):

There's also the JavaMelody project

"The goal of JavaMelody is to monitor Java or Java EE application servers in QA and production environments. It is not a tool to simulate requests from users, it is a tool to measure and calculate statistics on real operation of an application depending on the usage of the application by users"

[JavaMelody](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki)

Comment: Java Melody has the most simple way to implement on your java EE project...